# Share data between gitlab projects

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How could we share test data among different gitlab projects.
We have a centralized project containing test data which needs to be used by different projects while running their unit tests. So what would be the best way to import the test data in the test stage in corresponding .gitlab-ci.yml project file?

Answer (score 0):

The test data repository can be cloned at the beginning of `test` stage :

```
test:
  script:
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:$CI_JOB_TOKEN@gitlab/group/project_test_data.git
    - # run your tests using project_test_data
```

The `CI_JOB_TOKEN` will let you identified when cloning. cf : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html